# The combination of a last name prefix and honorifics

Tags: business-writing

I am trying to figure out if ti is correct to write either miss de Vries or miss De Vries.

I am Dutch and our rules sat it should be mevrouw(miss) De Vries if there is no first name or initials.
So, it's mevrouw De Vries and mevrouw S. de Vries.

What is the correct way in English?

I have searched quite a bit but I couldn't find the answer concerning the English grammar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically in English, the capitalization is preserved so "Miss de Vries" is acceptable.  Additionally, English tends to abbreviate the titles of people so it would be "Ms. de Vries" rather than Miss (Mr. for Mister, and Mrs. for Misses, which should only be used if the woman is married.  Way back, men had an unmarried title of "Master" that complimented "Mister" but the Master for unwed men is no longer in vogue.

Ultimately though it's more up to personal style for the capitalization rules.  The Eighth President of the United States preferred to capitalize his full name (Martin Van Buren) but his name at birth was "Martin van Buren".

Comment: *Ms.* is not an abbreviation of *Miss*.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ms.  Married and unmarried women are referred to with the title *Ms.* which is pronounced /ˈmɪz/.  *Miss* is not commonly abbreviated.

Answer (score 0):

When writing in Dutch you keep the 'D' in de Vries as it would be in the middle of a sentence after Mevrouw, just like in English in the first answer.
Some people, more in Belgium than in NL, use De Vries in all situations, in that case you keep the capital.

Only when it is really the first letter of a sentence you capitalize the 'D' when it is usually a small letter.

My name has two 'middle words' and in most cases they stay small, when at the start of a sentence only the first get capitalized, the actual main word of the name always get a capital.

When writing in a foreign language I keep to the Dutch rules, but people who write in those languages often apply their own rules, so if you look at examples on internet you may find all kind of different rules.